How to group consecutive time series days by category?
I have a dataframe that consists of daily categorical values for multiple locations. I'm trying to create a new dataframe that groups the consecutive days and standalone days for each categorical value at each location. I'm pretty new to coding and am having trouble figuring out grouping and filtering by the multiple arguments at once in dplyr. This is the code I have so far, the example starting dataframe and what I'm picturing for the new dataframe:
code:
#Rstudio
> new_df <- df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(Date) != 1))) %>% mutate(start_date== "") %>% mutate(end_date== "") %>% mutate(total_days == end_date - start_date)

df:



location
Date
category




site1
2007-11-03
cat1


site1
2007-11-04
cat1


site1
2007-11-05
cat3


site1
2007-11-06
cat2


site1
2007-11-07
cat2


site2
2007-11-06
cat2


site2
2007-11-07
cat2



new_df:



location
start_date
end_date
total_days
category




site1
2007-11-03
2007-11-04
2
cat1


site1
2007-11-05
2007-11-05
1
cat3


site1
2007-11-06
2007-11-07
2
cat2


site2
2007-11-06
2007-11-07
2
cat2




Your question mentions but the toy data doesn't include standalone days.

library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(
    start_date = min(Date),
    end_date = max(Date),
    total_days = n(),
    .by = c(location, category),
    .keep = "unused"
  ) |>
  distinct() |>
  relocate(category, .after = last_col())

# A tibble: 4 × 5
#  location start_date end_date   total_days category
#  <chr>    <date>     <date>          <int> <chr>   
#1 site1    2007-11-03 2007-11-04          2 cat1    
#2 site1    2007-11-05 2007-11-05          1 cat3    
#3 site1    2007-11-06 2007-11-07          2 cat2    
#4 site2    2007-11-06 2007-11-07          2 cat2  

Data:
df <- readr::read_table("
location    Date    category
site1   2007-11-03  cat1
site1   2007-11-04  cat1
site1   2007-11-05  cat3
site1   2007-11-06  cat2
site1   2007-11-07  cat2
site2   2007-11-06  cat2
site2   2007-11-07  cat2")


Your data mentions but the toy data doesn't included standalone days, but this possible solution takes it into consideration (toy data at the end).
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = c(location, category), 
    group_days = c(1, diff.Date(Date)),
    group_days = consecutive_id(cumsum(if_else(group_days == 1, 0, 1)))) %>% 
  
  summarise(
    .by  = c(location, category, group_days),
    start_date = min(Date),
    end_date   = max(Date),
    total_days = end_date - start_date + 1)

The output:
> new_df
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  location category group_days start_date end_date   total_days
  <chr>    <chr>         <int> <date>     <date>     <drtn>    
1 site1    cat1              1 2007-11-03 2007-11-04 2 days   # group: two days
2 site1    cat1              2 2007-11-06 2007-11-06 1 days   # standalone  
3 site1    cat1              3 2007-11-10 2007-11-12 3 days   # group: three days   
4 site1    cat3              1 2007-11-05 2007-11-05 1 days   # standalone
5 site1    cat2              1 2007-11-06 2007-11-09 4 days   # group: four days   
6 site2    cat2              1 2007-11-11 2007-11-15 5 days   # group: five days   
7 site2    cat2              2 2007-11-18 2007-11-18 1 days   # standalone   
8 site2    cat2              3 2007-11-20 2007-11-25 6 days   # group: six days


Toy data:
# Toy data
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~location,        ~Date, ~category,
    "site1", "2007-11-03",    "cat1", # group: two days
    "site1", "2007-11-04",    "cat1", 
  
    "site1", "2007-11-06",    "cat1", # standalone
  
    "site1", "2007-11-10",    "cat1", # group: three days
    "site1", "2007-11-11",    "cat1", 
    "site1", "2007-11-12",    "cat1",  
  
    "site1", "2007-11-05",    "cat3", # standalone
  
    "site1", "2007-11-06",    "cat2", # group: four days
    "site1", "2007-11-07",    "cat2",
    "site1", "2007-11-08",    "cat2",
    "site1", "2007-11-09",    "cat2",
  
    "site2", "2007-11-11",    "cat2", # group: five days
    "site2", "2007-11-12",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-13",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-14",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-15",    "cat2",
  
    "site2", "2007-11-18",    "cat2", # standalone
  
    "site2", "2007-11-20",    "cat2", #group: six days
    "site2", "2007-11-21",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-22",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-23",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-24",    "cat2",
    "site2", "2007-11-25",    "cat2")

my_df <- mutate(my_df, Date = ymd(Date))

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0
